# performing a clould_api web_detection search on a specific domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-sdk

I only want to see results from domains I specify. Is there a way to pass additional parameters to a web_detection query in order to provide greater result accuracy?

I am using the python vision google.cloud library.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it doesn't seem possible to provide a smaller subset of URLs to parse within the Cloud Vision web detection tool. A possible workaround could be disregard URLs that doesn't match your criteria using the [Python Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/index.html).